# cudaMemGetInfo returns same amount of free memory on both devices of GTX 690

Tags: memory, cuda, multi-gpu

I have run into problems with Geforce GTX 690 while trying to track down the memory usage. A simple test program:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(cudaMemoryTest) {

size_t mem_tot_0 = 0;
size_t mem_free_0 = 0;
size_t mem_tot_1 = 0;
size_t mem_free_1 = 0;

unsigned int mem_size = 100*1000000;

float* h_P = new float[mem_size];
for(size_t i = 0; i < mem_size; i++) {
    h_P[i] = 0.f;
}

cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaDeviceReset();
cudaMemGetInfo  (&mem_free_0, & mem_tot_0);
std::cout<<"Free memory before copy dev 0: "<<mem_free_0<<std::endl;

cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaDeviceReset();
cudaMemGetInfo  (&mem_free_1, &mem_tot_1);
std::cout<<"Free memory before copy dev 1: "<<mem_free_1<<std::endl;

cudaSetDevice(0);
float* P;
cudaMalloc((void**)&P, mem_size*sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpy((void*)P, h_P,  mem_size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaMemGetInfo(&mem_free_0, & mem_tot_0);
std::cout<<"Free memory after copy  dev 0: "<<mem_free_0<<std::endl;

cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaMemGetInfo(&mem_free_1, &mem_tot_1);
std::cout<<"Free memory after copy dev 1: "<<mem_free_1<<std::endl;

BOOST_CHECK(mem_free_0 != mem_free_1);

cudaError_t err;
err = cudaGetLastError();
if(err!=cudaSuccess)
    std::cout<<"an error occurred"<<std::endl;

cudaSetDevice(0);
destroyMem(P);
delete [] h_P;
}
```

The test prints out:

```
1>  Free memory before copy dev 0: 1733173248
1>  Free memory before copy dev 1: 1688424448
1>  Free memory after copy  dev 0: 1289940992
1>  Free memory after copy dev 1: 1289940992     
CudaUtilsTest.cpp(47): error in "cudaMemoryTest": check mem_free_0 != mem_free_1 failed
```

The problem is that after the allocation the amount of free memory on device 1 is exactly the same as on device 0, which shouldn't be the case, hence the problem has to be in cudaMemGetInfo and/or cudaSetDevice. Anyone run on the same problem, or is there something else fundamentally wrong in the test that someone can point out?

Running the code on Windows 7, Visual studio 2010, Cuda SDK 5.0, compiling with code generation: compute_30,sm_30

EDIT 22.4.2013

I continued experimenting with this issue and it seems that cudaSetDevice works fine as can be verified from the result of cudaGetDevice calls. I added a reset of device 0 after the memory allocation test and it seems that the size of free memory returned by cudaMemGetInfo is again same for both devices. I have checked all return values of cuda_error_t in my own code and all function calls return cudaSuccess. Have anyone run into similar problems with GTX 690 with the setup descibed above?

Most resent test code:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(cudaMemoryTest) {
size_t mem_tot_0 = 0;
size_t mem_free_0 = 0;
size_t mem_tot_1 = 0;
size_t mem_free_1 = 0;

int device_num = 0;

unsigned int mem_size = 100*1000000;

float* h_P = new float[mem_size];
for(size_t i = 0; i < mem_size; i++) {
    h_P[i] = 0.f;
}

cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaGetDevice(&device_num);
cudaDeviceReset();
cudaMemGetInfo  (&mem_free_0, & mem_tot_0);
std::cout<<"Free memory before copy dev 0: "<<mem_free_0<<" Device: "<<device_num<<std::endl;
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaGetDevice(&device_num);
cudaDeviceReset();
cudaMemGetInfo  (&mem_free_1, & mem_tot_1);
std::cout<<"Free memory before copy dev 1: "<<mem_free_1<<" Device: "<<device_num<<std::endl;
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaGetDevice(&device_num);
float* P;
cudaMalloc((void**)&P, mem_size*sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpy((void*)P, h_P,  mem_size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemGetInfo(&mem_free_0, & mem_tot_0);
std::cout<<"Free memory after copy  dev 0: "<<mem_free_0<<" Device: "<<device_num<<std::endl;
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaGetDevice(&device_num);
cudaMemGetInfo(&mem_free_1, &mem_tot_1);
std::cout<<"Free memory after copy dev 1: "<<mem_free_1<<" Device: "<<device_num<<std::endl;
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

BOOST_CHECK(mem_free_0 != mem_free_1);

cudaError_t err;
err = cudaGetLastError();
if(err!=cudaSuccess)
    std::cout<<"an error occurred"<<std::endl;

// Reset only device 0 and check both
cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaGetDevice(&device_num);
cudaDeviceReset();
cudaMemGetInfo  (&mem_free_0, & mem_tot_0);
std::cout<<"Free memory after second reset of device 0, dev 0: "<<mem_free_0<<" Device: "<<device_num<<std::endl;
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaGetDevice(&device_num);
cudaMemGetInfo  (&mem_free_1, & mem_tot_1);
std::cout<<"Free memory after second device reset of device 0, dev 1: "<<mem_free_1<<" Device: "<<device_num<<std::endl;
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

delete [] h_P;
    }
```

Test output:

```
1>  Free memory before copy dev 0: 1794379776 Device: 0
1>  Free memory before copy dev 1: 1751728128 Device: 1
1>  Free memory after copy  dev 0: 1351696384 Device: 0
1>  Free memory after copy dev 1: 1351696384 Device: 1
1>  CudaUtilsTest.cpp(353): error in "cudaMemoryTest": check mem_free_0 != mem_free_1 failed
1>  Free memory after second reset of device 0, dev 0: 1751728128 Device: 0
1>  Free memory after second device reset of device 0, dev 1: 1751728128 Device: 1
```

Comment: [cudaSetDevice](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g418c299b069c4803bfb7cab4943da383) returns an API level error code.  Perhaps you should do error checking on it.

Comment: I ran a version of your code on a K10 machine in linux (the closest I could get to your GTX690 in Windows) and had no trouble.  The size after copy dev 1 was the same as the size before copy dev 1.

Comment: Thanks for the test run! All the function calls return cudaSuccess though.

Comment: Solved: Switch "Disable multi-GPU mode" from NVIDIA control panel at "3D-settings" -> "Configure Multi-GPU, Surround, PhysX"

Answer (score 4):

This was solved by changed WDDM driver settings as follows:

> Switch "Disable multi-GPU mode" from NVIDIA control panel at
>   "3D-settings" -> "Configure Multi-GPU, Surround, PhysX".

[This answer added from comments as a community wiki entry to get the question off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag]